# React - Updating child

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm tryinng to update child based on the parent state.

In the parent:

```
<ImageGallery id={this.state.id} images={this.state.images} />
```

In the child:

```
  render(){
    console.log("Rendering.............. gallery ");
    console.log(this.props.images);
    var images =  this.props.images.map(function(image, i){
      return (
       <Image key={image.id} source={image.source} style={{width: 400, height: 400}}></Image>
      );
    });

    console.log("Array of images to render: => ");
    console.log(images);
    return (
      <View>{images}</View>
    );
  }
```

But render is only called once, because the original state is empty, the data is fetched on the parent's component did mount.

**EDIT** Answering questions

> how do you update the state of parent component and how you expect to update >child? – **havenchyk**

Because that state is being referenced on the child:

```
//Here
images={this.state.images}
```

**EDIT 2**

This is my component did mount:

1- Request a list of images objects
2- then getting those images as blob
3- using base64 to display image
4- creating the Source object to display on the  that will be used on the child
5- changing the state

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try{
      let response = await API.get(`communities/${this.state.id}/community-pictures`);

      let json = await response.json();

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw json;
      }

      let images = json.data;
      let newImages = [];

      images.forEach(async (image) => {
        let response = await API.request_blob(`communities/${this.state.id}/community-pictures/${image.id}/view`);
        let data = await response.base64();

        let type = response.respInfo.headers['Content-Type'];
        let imageUri = `data:${type};base64,` + data;

        let source = {uri: imageUri, scale: 1};

        newImages.push(Object.assign(image, {source: source}));
      });

      this.setState({
        images: newImages
      });

      console.log("Changing images!!");
      console.log(this.state);

    } catch (json) {
      // Surppressing this error
    }
  }
```

And you can checkout the child's render. It uses **this.props.images** to mount the screen. But not working. Parent changes it's states and the child doesn't update.

**EDIT SUPER WIERD** Guys I noticed something veryyyy strange. I put some console.log on componentDidMount to see the new state. Check OUT what chrome prints:

[image]

But, when I open the object to see the array, check it out:

[image]

WOW!! What's hapennin?!

Comment: how do you update the state of parent component and how you expect to update child?

Comment: Are you setting state in the parent after getting data in componentDidMount()? This would trigger another render.

Comment: can you please show the code where you fetch the data?

Comment: Yes @CodyParker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `images.forEach(async (image) => {` is being executed as async.

So when React is going to check whether it should render or not, it's comparing an empty array and renders nothing.

Then, those async calls are completed and as you changed the content of the same reference `newImages`, your console.log change.

The solution is to remove the async forEach, you could put everything inside an async function and invoke like this:

```
let images = json.data;
let newImages = [];

for (int index = 0; index < images.length; images++) {
    let img = await fetch(images[index]);
    newImages.push(img);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Nothing was wrong with my Parent/Child implementation on React. By doing what you said now the state changes correctly and so does the child. PS: dont need to override SCU!

Answer (score 2):

After you change the state of component via `setState(state)` you call rerender of current component, because default implementation of method `shouldComponentUpdate` return true if the state of component is not equal to the next state. You can read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

So, your component is updated, and `render()` method was called. Next react called `shouldComponentUpdate` of the child elements.

There is an example of how react rendering elements.
[image: Should component update scheme]

There `vDOMEq` indicates whether the rendered React elements were equivalent or no. [There](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html) is documentation about it.

So when you update props of the child component `SCU`  returns `false` so rerendering is not needed. How can avoid this? Simply implement `SCU` by yourself.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   nextProps.propToChange !== this.props.propToChange
}
```

Remember to not mutate your props, because if you will - equal checking will return false (because refs are the same) and you will get some unexpected errors.

Comment: So if the default implementation is always true when the state changes. So the best way to go is to change the state of the child right? But how can I do that If I receive the props only on the constructor? Or how would I share the state without having to create a High-Order component (thus, they will share the same state)

Comment: The best way of implementation of thus (change child depends on parent) - is to pass the state of parent via props and implement `SCU` by yourself to rerender element, when props are changed, but if you receive props only in constructor(its really strange, why? how would you update your state) - set state depend on props in constructor `this.state  = {...}`.

Comment: My class only has the constructor receiving props and the render function. I'll implement **shouldComponentUpdate**. And see if it works.

Comment: That method was never called :(

Comment: You need to update props of this component from the parent to call this mehtod

Comment: React updates it for me when I do:

<ImageGallery id={this.state.id} images={this.state.images} />

Right?

Comment: When state (id and images ) are changed

Comment: I change the state on **componentDidMount**. I checked here, the SCU is being called. Put some debug lines there...`console.log(nextProps);`

But the images inside nextProps are empty!!! (Even though the parent's state is correct)

Comment: Dmitriy I updated my question. Please check it out. Look what's hapenning when I set the state. Maybe that's why SCU is getting empty nextProps.

Comment: Seems that you mutate your state. Check there - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

Comment: Dmitriy, turns out that the problem was on the async part of my code. But your answer is pretty useful and contains alot of information that might help others. Thank you for your help!